# How to do a ONLINE „Buzzer“ in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, 2d

Ok so I want to have a pressable Button. And whenever someone presses it (on their computer in another network) I want my game to react to it.

It should work like this website:
https://buzzin.live/

People should be able to log in with a username and press a button. I tried searching how to do smt like this but I haven‘t found an answer.

Networking is a really weird topic with very few tutorials (and most of the tutorials are about online fps‘) so I hope to get help here :)

Comment: It sounds like you may need a networking layer like [Photon](https://www.photonengine.com/) (which is free for a certain amount of low concurrents, but provides paid options for bigger amounts).

Answer (score 1):

I see two options

1. Unity's client server networking seems a bit intense for a simple event implementation.
   What I would do if I were you is look into WebSocket servers (more than pure tcp servers since usually websocket libraries are easier to use than pure tcp)
2. Either that or you could look into Unity messaging API which doesn't require to support the whole multiplayer shebang, just simple message passing. I would do some research into Unity's Network Messages and look around.
   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html
   Setting up a simple client-server project is pretty straight forward and Unity manages the connection for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got it to work using Photon already. I took me a bit of time, but it’s working now. Thank you anyway :)